# LLVM execution engine cannot find my function

Tags: c++, llvm

I am using LLVM's `ExecutionEngine` to run a module. The module contains a function called `blub` that returns `5`. In C:

```
int blub() {
  int x = 5;
  return x;
}
```

Here is my C++ code for executing "blub":

```
// Print out all of the functions, just to see
for (auto& function : M->functions()) {
  std::cout << function.getName().str() << std::endl;
}

auto engine = EngineBuilder(std::move(M)).create();

engine->finalizeObject();

using MyFunc = int();
auto func = (MyFunc*)engine->getPointerToNamedFunction("blub");

auto result = func();

std::cout << "result is " << result << std::endl;
```

It should print out the names of all functions (just "blub") and then the result, "5".

However, I get this error instead:

```
blub
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function 'blub' which could not be resolved!
```

So the function is indeed in the module, but it cannot be resolved by the `ExecutionEngine`. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation of `getPointerToNamedFunction`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html#a9148561629d9476edf2fbf18a1f046a0) (emphasis mine):

> getPointerToNamedFunction - This method returns the address of the specified function by using the **dlsym** function call.
>
> **As such it is only useful for resolving library symbols, not code generated symbols.**

You should instead call [`findFunctionNamed`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html#a7fa64d2f41d7a7fed1a604bc028c8bde) and then [`runFunction`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html#ac65a03b7fbdb7acd7be0bae506238c9d) on the result.